# Disable automatic iPod scrobbling through rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, Rhythmbox 2.97.

I use Rhythmbox to manage my ipod, so far so good. But every time I plug it in, what I've listened on my ipod to get scrobbled to last.fm automatically.

I wish to disable that (but keep the regular scrobbling functionality ), but am having a tough time figuring out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how often you plug in your iPod, but one option is to untick "Submit listening data" just before you plug it in and turn it on again right after. I'm fairly certain your iPod will won't try to scrobble again if that is turned off. All those scrobbles will be gone from the iPod as well though.

[image]